# How to avoid ligatures within option-tag?

Tags: html-select, font-awesome-5, ligature

I'd like to create a visually appealing select-dialog that shows FontAwesome-Icons and a word describing the symbol to select from various scales for statistical data.

So I'm using the FontAwesome-Fonts for the `select`-tag and the unicode-glyphs for the various symbols. That first part works nicely. 
But the words I am using are also used in FonAwesome to form ligatures that can also be used to get the icons (I thought this was limited to the [desktop](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/referencing-icons/using-ligatures)-version, but as my example prooves, it also happens on the web). The FA-Site [states](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) that they are "...aren't comfortable considering ligatures for Web Fonts + CSS".

Please check out my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/dwgxhjpu/) or the screenshot:

[image]

So, my questions are:

- if it's not supposed to happen with Webfonts/CSS - is there anything that I am doing wrong using them? (Of course I have the desktop-fonts installed on my machine, I guess we won't know if users of the website will have them or not)
- is there any way I can avoid the ligatures taking effect within the `option`-tag? (as you see in the sample, I am already using `font-variant-ligatures: none;` in the CSS)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't actually demonstrate much; it doesn't even have the FA icons. Can you tell us which words in the example produce ligatures?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the fiddle (takesn with the latest Chrome). Interesting though that it doesn't show the icons for you. (I know it doesn't work on IOS, but everywhere else if should)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this by defining dedicated `@font-faces` with a different name. (My theory is that Chrome uses the local font I have installed and that it's ligatures override everything I do in CSS). That "special font-face" is sure not to be found locally...

If someone finds a better explanation or fix, I'll happily accept it.