# Font Awesome unicode icon is not working in firefox

Tags: html, font-awesome, html-select

Here is my html code.

```
  <label><b>Phone Verified : </b></label>
  <select class="form-control phone_verified">
      <option value="">Select Option</option>
      <option value="1">Yes (&#xf00c;)</option>
      <option value="0">No (&#xf00d;)</option>
  </select>
```

I've linked cdn bootstrap link

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style type="text/css">
  select  {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'open sans'
}
</style>
```

In my **chrome browser** icon working perfect.

[image]

But in **firefox not** working.

[image]

I followed this [font awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

check JSFiddle Link :- https://jsfiddle.net/17j8pxqb/

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle and can confirm what you found, it works in Chrome, but not in Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/9dz8a5kc/1/

Comment: Oddly, it's fine after you select the option, but not while you are viewing the list. By the way, same issue in Safari.

Comment: Thank you for your answer KIKo. Here i've added firefox image in that image you can see Yes(FOOC) something.

Comment: I did find this question, it seems related, but is unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884774/css-font-family-support-dropped-for-select-in-firefox It seems to be a bug.

Comment: You assume perfect @aynber that's what i've an issue.

Comment: Based on the jsfiddle, it doesn't work for me in Chrome either. To ensure crossbrowser-safety here, maybe you should try using Select2, or some other third party improvement on the default select-boxes.

Comment: <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> use this link please

Comment: A simple alternative is to use unicode characters [CHECK MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) and [MULTIPLICATION X](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2715/index.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a workaround, a solution and some reasoning why this is happening...

### Workaround: just use any `fa-style on your page.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/zLapqy3u/

### Solution: declare `font-face`

Add the `font-face`-declaration from FA's CSS:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.1') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.1') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.1') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.1') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.1#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.1');
}
```

Note that you this code refers to some font-files which you will need to provide as well.

Actually...it would recommend to not call this font `FontAwesome`, because that could overlap with FA and cause unintended side-effects. Better use a unique name. To be clear:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome_Dilip';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.1') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.1') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.1') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.1') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.1#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.1');
}
```

and

`select  {
  font-family: '`**FontAwesome_Dilip**`', 'open sans'
}`

Also I want to suggest using a specific style for this font-family in preference to applying it to all `select`-controls.

### Possible explanation

It might be some sort of optimization where FF does not bother processing the `@font-face-declation` from FA-CSS, because it is not used (none of the actual styles from the CSS is referenced.). So then my simple `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>` fixed it...

### Bonus: another advantage of the "private" font-face

As long as you only use `yes` or `no` in the select, everything is fine. Try adding the word `Key`to your options just to see what's possible (*this is an effect which wasn't generally reproducible, but using Chrome I [had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348677/how-to-avoid-ligatures-within-option-tag/57354376#57354376) this very problem. But I'm also using FontAwesome-Font in my Windows-System and I suspect this caused the effect.)*: you may end up seeing the smybol twice, because "key" is used as a ligature in the font-definition to generate the same symbol. So the advantage of declaring a font-face specifically for that usage is that you can add `font-variant-ligatures: none;` to the CSS-Style for `select` to disable ligatures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer let me test with it.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is an old issue with several browsers, especially Firefox on Mac OS X. There is a hack where you add a "multiple" attribute to the select tag, but this will alter the nature of your dropdown box and can result in unwanted input from the users.

```
 <select multiple class="form-control phone_verified">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="1">Yes (&#xf00c;)</option>
  <option value="0">No (&#xf00d;)</option>
  </select>
```

[Working solution on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb4u9sxd/)

[Issue on Github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/996)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer is working if I use `multiple` but if I remove `multiple` same issue occuring.

Comment: If you want cross-browser functionality, I'm afraid you will have to implement an own dropdown solution, or just use an existing solution from a library like Bootstrap or jQuery. Just as the last comment in the issues section on GitHub states: "Please implement a JavaScript solution if you want this to work across browsers and platforms"

Comment: It means i've to use another library for it like boostrap-select https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/ right?

Comment: No, unfortunately that plugin still uses a select tag, which means ultimately you'll end up with the same problem. But there are many working solutions with list tags (ul, li), like in vanilla Bootstrap: (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is inclusion of -webkit or -moz in your css document.
Chrome supports it but for mozilla to support this use "-moz-".

For further information on this go to the link below and you'll find everything related to it!!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know more about webkit. can you made for select tag which will working for firefox?